# Click Event for Dynamically Generate Linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

i created a simple registration page which have fields Name,Username and Password.. actually am checking the username with database whether that username already had or not...

[image]

suppose if that username already taken,then i display"Username Already Taken" message in label,and also i create dynamically 4 link buttons for username suggestions like

[image]

now when i click on linkbuttons,that are bind to username textbox.. here is my code

[image]

give me some idea how to bind that linkbutton to textbox..

Comment: Paste your code here as a **text**, not as an image..

Comment: Create a click event for the linkbutton and in that event copy linkbutton's text to textbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should minimize server requests from client, especially if you want to update UI controls.   I suggest to use java script to update text box with new value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   LinkButton lbtn = new LinkButton();
   lbtn.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + txtuname.ClientID + "').value = '"+txtuname.Text + i+"'; return false;";
   lbtn.Text = txtuname.Text + i;
   phlinks.Controls.Add(lbtn);
   phlinks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   LinkButton lbtn = new LinkButton();
   lbtn.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + txtuname.ClientID + "').value = this.innerText; return false;";
   lbtn.Text = i.ToString();
   phlinks.Controls.Add(lbtn);
}
```